# Can anyone help me to provide a link that provides the designing of memory unit and control unit by using Finite State Machines in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

Can anyone please help me to provide a link that provides the designing of memory unit and control unit by using Finite State Machines in VHDL?

I need to design the architecture of a circuit.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of online resources that can help you. For example [here](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~ece327/protected/modelsim/htmldocs/modelsim_se_user/a_vhdl36.html):

```
architecture style_87 of memory is
begin
memory:
process (cs)
    -----------------------
    variable ram : ram_type;
    -----------------------
    variable address : natural;
    begin
        if rising_edge(cs) then
            address := sulv_to_natural(add_in);
            if (mwrite = '1') then
                 ram(address) := data_in;
            end if;
            data_out <= ram(address);
        end if;
    end process;
end style_87;
```

Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001025/implementing-a-fsm-in-vhdl):

```
process(currentstate, a)
begin
    b <= '1';
    c <= '1';
    case currentstate is
        when s1 =>
            if (a = '1') then
                c <= '0';
            end if;

            nextstate <= s2;

        when s2 =>
            -- b doesnt change state from s1 to here, do I need to define what it is here?
            if (a /= '1') then
            c <= '0';
        end if;

        nextstate <= s3;

    when s3 =>
        if (a = '1') then
            b <= '0';
            c <= '0';
        end if;

        nextstate <= s1;
    end case;
end process;
```

I'm sure you can Google a lot of other examples by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[CHAPTER 10 FINITE STATE MACHINE:PRINCIPLE AND PRACTICE](http://academic.csuohio.edu/chu_p/rtl/chu_rtL_book/rtl_chap10_fsm.pdf)  (PDF, 274KB) out of the book by Pong P.Chu, RTL Hardware Design Using VHDL, Coding for Efficiency, Portability, and Scalability.

See Figure 10.3 State diagram of a memory controller FSM.  Note that the chapter doesn't demonstrate a model directly, it teaches you everything you need to know to design one, without dwelling on implementation specific device timing, or specificly on memory controllers.

The same state diagram is found in some course slides, [Hardware Design with VHDL Finite State Machines ECE 443](http://www.ece.unm.edu/~jimp/vhdl_fpgas/slides/FSM.pdf) along with other chapter content and some VHDL source  implementing a memory controller.